# Merging columns in df like dataframes - obtaining rows with same values across columns in df

Tags: r, dataframe

I spent some time to find solution, however I failed... just like in the title, actually I don't know how to explain, so example df:

```
A <- c('ABC','GHI',rep(NA,3))
B <- c('AAB','ABC','BCE','CAB',NA)
C <- c('ABC','BCE','GHI','XXX','ZZZ')
D <- c('BCE',rep(NA,4))
E <- c('GHI','ZZZ','BAR',rep(NA,2))
df <- data.frame(A,B,C,D,E)

     A    B   C    D    E
1  ABC  AAB ABC  BCE  GHI
2  GHI  ABC BCE <NA>  ZZZ
3 <NA>  BCE GHI <NA>  BAR
4 <NA>  CAB XXX <NA> <NA>
5 <NA> <NA> ZZZ <NA> <NA>
```

And now I'd like to reorder rows to have same values in each row or `NA` if particular value doesn't exist in some column. Desired output:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
1   ABC ABC ABC NA  NA
2   GHI NA  GHI NA  GHI
3   NA  AAB NA  NA  NA
4   NA  BCE BCE BCE NA
5   NA  NA  ZZZ NA  ZZZ
6   NA  NA  XXX NA  NA
7   NA  NA  NA  NA  BAR
8   NA  CAB NA  NA  NA
```

The order doesn't matter, could you please give me a hint how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pivot the data to long and then back to wide.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(id = value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id)

# # A tibble: 8 × 6
#   id    A     B     C     D     E    
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 ABC   ABC   ABC   ABC   NA    NA   
# 2 AAB   NA    AAB   NA    NA    NA   
# 3 BCE   NA    BCE   BCE   BCE   NA   
# 4 GHI   GHI   NA    GHI   NA    GHI  
# 5 ZZZ   NA    NA    ZZZ   NA    ZZZ  
# 6 BAR   NA    NA    NA    NA    BAR  
# 7 CAB   NA    CAB   NA    NA    NA   
# 8 XXX   NA    NA    XXX   NA    NA
```

Equivalent `base` way:

```r
reshape(transform(na.omit(stack(df)), id = values),
        direction = "wide", idvar = "id", timevar = "ind", v.names = "values")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `match`

```
> sapply(df, \(x) x[match(unique(unlist(df)), x)]) |> as.data.frame()
     A    B    C    D    E
1  ABC  ABC  ABC <NA> <NA>
2  GHI <NA>  GHI <NA>  GHI
3 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
4 <NA>  AAB <NA> <NA> <NA>
5 <NA>  BCE  BCE  BCE <NA>
6 <NA>  CAB <NA> <NA> <NA>
7 <NA> <NA>  XXX <NA> <NA>
8 <NA> <NA>  ZZZ <NA>  ZZZ
9 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  BAR
```

Sorted version:

```
> sapply(df, \(x) x[match(sort(unique(unlist(df))), x)]) |> as.data.frame()
     A    B    C    D    E
1 <NA>  AAB <NA> <NA> <NA>
2  ABC  ABC  ABC <NA> <NA>
3 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  BAR
4 <NA>  BCE  BCE  BCE <NA>
5 <NA>  CAB <NA> <NA> <NA>
6  GHI <NA>  GHI <NA>  GHI
7 <NA> <NA>  XXX <NA> <NA>
8 <NA> <NA>  ZZZ <NA>  ZZZ
```

Answer (score 2):

In base R we could do

```r
vals <- na.omit(unique(unlist(df)))
as.data.frame(lapply(df, \(x) ifelse(vals %in% x, vals, NA)))
#>      A    B    C    D    E
#> 1  ABC  ABC  ABC <NA> <NA>
#> 2  GHI <NA>  GHI <NA>  GHI
#> 3 <NA>  AAB <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 4 <NA>  BCE  BCE  BCE <NA>
#> 5 <NA>  CAB <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 6 <NA> <NA>  XXX <NA> <NA>
#> 7 <NA> <NA>  ZZZ <NA>  ZZZ
#> 8 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  BAR
```